# Method to calculate ionospheric error, SNR, tropospheric error from RINEX files with Python

Tags: python, gps, spatial

I'm looking to calculate atmospheric error, SNR, MP, CNR from a batch of RINEX files (2.11). I'd like to then write the output to an array for spatial and statistical analysis.

Are there any Python packages that can do what I'm looking for? Many thanks!

From what I've observed, many of the software packages that do what I need are written in C, however I'm only proficient in Python and MATLAB. GNSStk has a Python API, but no documentation.